# Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd in C

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, valgrind, free

i'm developing a program that should read line from a file and retrieve information manipulating them. The file in question is:

```
WORD abc
TOTAL 10
FILE /home/user/Scrivania/find/try
OCCURRENCES 2
0 0
1 0
FILE /home/user/Scrivania/find/try1
OCCURRENCES 2
3 0
4 0
FILE /home/user/Scrivania/prova/prova1/prova3/try3
OCCURRENCES 3
2 0
3 0
4 0
FILE /home/user/Scrivania/prova/try4
OCCURRENCES 3
2 0
3 0
4 0
WORD ac
TOTAL 10
FILE /home/user/Scrivania/find/try
OCCURRENCES 3
2 0
3 0
4 0
FILE /home/user/Scrivania/find/try1
OCCURRENCES 3
0 0
1 0
2 0
FILE /home/user/Scrivania/prova/prova1/prova3/try3
OCCURRENCES 2
0 0
10
FILE /home/user/Scrivania/prova/try4
OCCURRENCES 2
0 0
1 0
```

I use this method:

```
void getWordOccurences(char *word, char *file, char *fileToCheck){
    FILE *f;
    char *curr = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t line_size;
    char *currentWord = NULL;
    char *currentFile = NULL;
    char *p = NULL;
    int check = 0;

    if(fileToCheck == NULL){
        printf("Pass a file as arguments\r\n");
    }else{
        f = fopen(file, "r");
        if(f == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s, exiting. . .\n", file);
            exit(1);
        }
        while((line_size = getline(&curr, &len, f)) != -1){
            trimTrailing(curr);
            if(curr[0] == 'W'){
                currentWord = (char*)malloc((strlen(curr)+1)*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(currentWord, strchr(curr, ' '));
                currentWord++;
                continue;
            }
            if(curr[0] == 'F'){
                currentFile = (char*)malloc((strlen(curr)+1)*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(currentFile, strchr(curr, ' '));
                currentFile++;
                continue;
            }
            if(curr[0] == 'O'){
                p = (char*)malloc((strlen(curr)+1)*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(p, strchr(curr, ' '));
                p++;
                continue;
            }
            if(strcmp(currentWord, word) == 0){
                if(strcmp(currentFile, fileToCheck) == 0){ // LINE 414
                    if(atoi(p) > 0){
                        check = 1;
                        printf("%s \n", curr);
                        continue;
                    }
                }         
            }
        }

        if(check == 0){
            printf("The word %s doesn't occur in the file %s \n", word, fileToCheck);
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

I pass to this method the parameters as input argunents. The variable `word` store to word to search, `file` store the path of the file to open (in this case, the file showed above) and `fileToCheck` is the file path to be searched inside the file (the one immediately after `FILE`).

I can pass every string i want as input arguments in the variable `word` except of `abc`. Only if i pass `abc` i get: (valgrind running)

```
==2447== Invalid read of size 1
==2447==    at 0x4FA5D60: __strcmp_ssse3 (strcmp.S:144)
==2447==    by 0x10A21D: getWordOccurences (find.c:414)
==2447==    by 0x108F3E: main (find.c:44)
==2447==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I don't get why this happen only in i pass `abc` as arguments. 
In the main method i only call this function, nothing else:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
      getWordOccurences(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);

      return 0;
}
```

The running command is :

```
valgrind myprog abc inputFile /home/users/Scrivania/find/try
```

I know that Is caused by a null pointer in line 414, but why i pass 'ac' it works and not with 'abc'?

Comment: `currentWord++;` `currentFile++;` `p++;` what are these lines supposed to do?

Comment: I don't understand what the program is trying to accomplish.

Comment: You can't `strcmp` a null pointer.

Comment: Valgrind is pointing out that you're trying to read 1 byte from address `0x0` (aka `NULL`), which isn't going to work... So either `currentFile` or `fileToCheck` are `NULL` on line `414`... (Most likely `currentFile`)

Comment: The program should read the input file and return the position occerrences of the word passed in input, in the fileToCheck passed in input. For example, if i pass abc and home/user/scrivania/try, It should return 0 0 and 0 1.

Comment: All the ++ are used to delete the blank space at the beginning of the string returned by strchr.

Comment: What about freeing allocated (by `malloc()`) memory? There will be memory leak. And probably you will not be able to free() this memory, because pointers are modified (by `++` operator).

Comment: If you're pursuing this on the current path, you seem to need a need a state machine for this. Right now you sort-of have one, but its terminating states (positions where you stop processing something and reset back to prior states) isn't well-defined. Regardless, the pointer actions like `currentFile++;` are flat-wrong. They will leave you with un-`free`-able pointers.

Comment: Can i use strrchr instead of ++ or it's the same? @WhozCraig

Comment: I wouldn't do *either*. I would be hunting for `WORD` announcements, once found, allocate space to hold the remainder of the line, then use `sscanf` with `%s` to slurp the word token with leading and trailing whitespace ignored for you (because that's what `sscanf` will do automatically). Regardless, think about the *states* you need for this endeavor, and what can/should be ignored or trigger state changes. that's really where you should be focusing before writing a line of code.

Comment: `strcpy(currentWord, strchr(curr, ' '));` is obviously a problem if there are no more spaces in the string. The suggested modification with `sscanf` is no help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem i added a control in the three if at the bottom:

```
if(currentWord != NULL && (strcmp(currentWord, word) == 0)){
     if(currentFile != NULL && (strcmp(currentFile, fileToCheck) == 0)){
          if(p != NULL && (atoi(p) > 0)){
                check = 1;
                printf("%s \n", curr);
                continue;
           }
     }         
}
```

And also i changed these portion of code:

```
strcpy(currentWord, strchr(curr, ' '));
currentWord++;

strcpy(currentFile, strchr(curr, ' '));
currentFile++;

strcpy(p, strchr(curr, ' '));
p++;
```

With these more performant lines:

```
sscanf(strchr(curr, ' '), "%s", currentWord);
sscanf(strchr(curr, ' '), "%s", currentFile);
sscanf(strchr(curr, ' '), "%s", p);
```